# Ubuntu, How to Enable Forced GPU on HP Pavilion

Tags: graphics, hp, bios, gpu, ubuntu-mate

I recently installed Ubuntu MATE on an HP Pavilion dv6 (XG759UA#ABA) to be a dedicated Minecraft machine. MATE works perfectly, but Minecraft insists upon using integrated graphics instead of the GPU. I read somewhere that HP has two settings "Dynamic" and "Forced" GPU. If set on Dynamic, openGL uses integrated instead of the CPU. I read that there is a way to change this in BIOS, but my BIOS does not give me this option.

I have tried to update the BIOS which should give me the option to change this, but I cannot figure out how to update the BIOS on Linux. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Probebly you have a system with double graphic card, since the dv6 is a laptop. Try [installing the proprietary driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) and configure the graphic card to use in the Catalyst control center.

Comment: Read my solution here: [AMD-AMD Switchable GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117612/amd-amd-switchable-gpu)